# CryEngine v start working from standard SDK

Tags: cryengine

I am a unity developer and i am new to CryEngine i use version V(5).
I recently found this on the marketplace: https://www.cryengine.com/marketplace/product/cryengine-gamesdk-sample-project

But is it possible to start working from this standard game? 
If so how can i edit the coding? for instance i want to edit the menu. How is this possible?

I can't find my answer on the docs and the CryEngine forum isn't working aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact this project was the standard project for CryEngine until CE4.
It is huge and some people say it is too messed up to start a full new game but for starters it is good to learn how the Engine is being used.

For coding you need visual studio and if you want to use c# (which I assume for a unity developer) you need some more stuff explained [here](http://docs.cryengine.com/display/CEPROG/CE%23+Framework).

In general I would recommend to click through the [docs](http://docs.cryengine.com). They might not be as easy and detailed as you are used from Unity but for the most basic things they are sufficient. If you more documents and help, check out the forums and of course the original code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment sadly i can't make any topics on the cryengine forum it just redirects me to the home page. I just don't know where i can start coding? i just want to make a basic menu and then see further what to do. But the docs aren't that easy as in unity. It's realy hard if you are new to CryEngine

Comment: There are the tutorials for the new Engine that are a good starter: https://www.cryengine.com/tutorials
For Coding check out the link I sent you, if you don't mind working with C++, then open the solution file delivered with the Engine and open it in Visual Studio